# Current activities not reflecting immediately. Why?

Tags: feature-request

After sign in, if I do some activity on the current page. E.g if I accept an answer, then as per the rule my reputation should increase by 2 and it increases also but the updated reputation is not showing immediately. To see the updated reputation I have to refresh the page again.

This kind of situation also happens when some new data is coming to my inbox.

Isn't it possible to implement push technology to immediately show the updated things. If it is possible, then why stackoverflow doesn't implement it?

Comment: I think this is too trivial for developer attention. Sometimes the effort required to do such UI changes could be a massive overhead for their implementation

Comment: What kind of overhead man, how facebook, google and all other sites are working?

Comment: this is a free community which focuses on knowledge sharing and not usability as a goal. while usability is important to SE sites(it actually boasts of it). I don't think this feature request fits in on its own

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To implement the reputation update properly, you would have to have Javascript or jQuery that automatically updates the reputation figure at the top of the page, and on any of your posts on the page.

That's just for your reputation update; it doesn't cover any manner of other updates, like the reputation of others when you downvote or accept an answer, etc.  The logic can become quite complex, and it's all client-side; i.e. it doesn't necessarily accurately reflect what's going on in the database. What happens if someone upvotes or downvotes one of your other posts during this time?

In the end, it's much easier (and more consistent with the Post-Redirect-Get pattern that the SE software uses) to just require people to refresh the page.  Stack Overflow is not a video game, although it might be considered [the world's largest MMORPG.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-worlds-largest-mmorpg-youre-playing-it-right-now.html)

Comment: *"Stack Overflow is not a video game, although it might be considered the world's largest MMORPG."* ...Maybe that's why it's addicting! :O

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure its possible.  But why?  The stackexchange sites are Q&A sites that focus on quality questions and great answers. Most of the team effort is (and should be) put in that direction.

And yes, its fun to get reputation and badges. But do you really want them within seconds or are you prepared to wait for a moment (time you can spend answering questions or using your privileges to improve the site).